# Subclassing a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, subclassing

I would like to make a subclassed jQuery wrapper that has all the methods jQuery has plus some more. I would also like to override some jQuery methods. Here is an example of what I would like to achieve

```
  calendar('.cal').showPopup()
                  .selectDate(new Date())
                  .addClass('popup-visible');
  alert(calendar.val());
```

Note that calendar works just like the jQuery object *except*

- It has some additional methods (showPopup and selectDate)
- It has an overridden method (val)
- When using method chaining, the Calendar object is returned. This means that addClass shouldn't revert back to a jQuery object.

I'll be grateful if someone points me in the right direction. I've been playing with scopes and $.extend and prototypes but can't seem to get anything to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that jQuery 1.5 has a new method called sub :)

According to the documentation, sub

> creates a new copy of
>   jQuery whose properties and methods
>   can be modified without affecting the
>   original jQuery object. 
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/

This method didn't allow you to subclass a subclass but I found a modified method in their ticket tracker that allowed this:

```
jQuery.subclass = function(){
  function jQuerySubclass( selector, context ) {
    return new jQuerySubclass.fn.init( selector, context );
  }
  jQuery.extend(true, jQuerySubclass, this);
  jQuerySubclass.superclass = this;
  jQuerySubclass.fn = jQuerySubclass.prototype = this();
  jQuerySubclass.fn.constructor = jQuerySubclass;
  jQuerySubclass.fn.init = function init( selector, context ) {
    if (context && context instanceof jQuery && !(context instanceof jQuerySubclass)){
      context = jQuerySubclass(context);
    }
    return jQuery.fn.init.call( this, selector, context, rootjQuerySubclass );
  };
  jQuerySubclass.fn.init.prototype = jQuerySubclass.fn;
  var rootjQuerySubclass = jQuerySubclass(document);
  return jQuerySubclass;
};
```

This allows you to do something like this:

```
var Calendar = jQuery.subclass();
Calendar.create = function() {
  var cal = Calendar( /* some html code for building the calendar */ );

  // Do some processing like binding events, etc

  return cal;
}
Calendar.fn.val = function(value) {
  //Calendar's implementation of val
}
```

The Calendar object will act just like a jQuery object *except* for those differences above. It will also correctly return an instance of Calendar when I chain methods together. This is neat because

- We can easily build custom widgets
  without cluttering the jQuery
  namespace.
- We can provide our own implementations of jQuery methods
- We can make use of jQuery's power with methods like trigger and bind already part of the class

Next, I'm interested in allowing classes to be registered by selector. This way, when you call $('.MyAwesomeCalendar'), you'll get back a Calendar object without having to explicitly call Calendar('.MyAwesomeCalendar').

Comment: for your last comment, about having different subclasses assigned by css class, are you looking for something cleaner than redefining $.fn.init?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start out by saying that I think you should dig a little further into jQuery's `$.fn` plugin method. You can read more about it here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

I would accomplish the above like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.calendar = function(){
    //do something useful
    return this; // necessary for chaining
  };
  $.fn.calendar.showPopup = function(){
    //do something useful
    return this; //necessary for chaining
  }
)(jQuery);
```

So, that being said. Your above example would require a similar syntax to return jQuery to your `calendar` function, and that will have to return Calendar's `this` to allow for chaining. I can't prove this code below but it's a good start:

```
var Calendar = (function($){
  calendar = {
    showPopup : function($){
      //do something useful
      return $; //required for chaining
    },
    val : function($){
      //return your inherent functionality
      return $; //required for chaining
     }

  }  
});
var calendar = new Calendar(jQuery);
```

Like I said, it's ugly and not at all how it should be done.

I'm not a javascript expert - but I believe that's how that is accomplished. I'll welcome any criticism as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking for a way that allowed polymorphism. For example, a new widget I created would have a different implementation of val().

Comment: No worries. The above answer is stellar, and surprised me - I hadn't seen that feature in the new 1.5 documentation. Looks like it's exactly what you want!